# Separating parts of a class which depend on a 3rd party API into a separate assembly

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, factory-pattern

I'm developing an application that processes objects from 3rd party .NET API. Processors are created by implementing the following `IProcessor` interface.

```
public interface IProcessor
{
    Process(ApiClass input);
}
```

Concrete implementations of this interface may also add other properties to control how the specific processors work. For example...

```
public class ProcessorA : IProcessor
{
    public double X;
    public double Y;

    public Process(ApiClass input)
    {
       //Code here...
    }
}

public class ProcessorB : IProcessor
{
    public string MyParameter;
    public string MyOtherParameter;

    public Process(ApiClass input)
    {
       //Code here...
    }
}
```

The third party API and `ApiClass` only function from inside the native application. However, I would like to be able to create other .NET assemblies that are able to read and write Processors, but do not need to reference the 3rd party API. Specifically I want to be able to serialize/deserialize processors to/from JSON.

So, I'm trying to determine the best way to split the parameters of a Processor and its implementation of `IProcessor.Process()` into two separate assemblies. One that references the 3rd party API and another that doesn't.

One option would be to make duplicate proxy versions of the objects.

```
//In assembly that does NOT reference 3rd party API
public class ProcessorAProxy
{
    public double X;
    public double Y;
}

//In assembly that references 3rd party API
public class ProcessorA 
{
    public double X;
    public double Y;

    public Process(ApiClass input)
    {
       //Code here...
    }
}
```

But this would require that I keep the properties in sync between these classes. I would also have to write mapping code to translate between them.

Another option would be to store the parameters in the proxy class, and then create a class that inherits from this class which adds the `Process()` method.

```
//In assembly that does NOT reference 3rd party API
public class ProcessorA
{
    public double X;
    public double Y;
}

//In assembly that references 3rd party API
public class ProcessorA : ProcessorAProxy
{
    public Process(ApiClass input)
    {
       //Code here...
    }
}
```

This option no longer has duplicate properties that I need to keep in sync. Yet if I deserialized a `ProcessorAProxy` I'm not sure how I could then convert it to a real `ProcessorA` with out having to deal with mapping values again.

Alternative to inheriting classes I could also inject the options into the class that actually does the processing through its constructor.

```
//In assembly that does NOT reference 3rd party API
public class ProcessorAOptions: IOptions 
{
    public double X;
    public double Y;
}

//In assembly that references 3rd party API
public class ProcessorA : IProcessor
{ 
   public ProcessorAOptions Options;

   public ProcessorA(ProcessorAOptions opt)
   {
       Options = opt;
   }

    public Process(ApiClass input)
    {
       //Code here...
    }
}
```

I would then deserialize a specific type of `IOptions`, which would then need to get passed to the constructor of the correct concrete type of `IProcessor`. This could be handled by a `ProcessorFactory`.

```
IOptions options = serializer.Read(); //Read the some options
ProcessorFactory fact = new ProcessorFactory(); //Create a factory
IProcessor proc = fact.GetProcessor(options); //Get the processor for options from the factory
```

So far I like this option the best, but I'm not sure the best way for the `ProcessorFactory` to map from a specific types of `IOptions` to the correct `IProcessor` type.

One option would be to create a giant if statement that checks for each option, type.

```
if(opt.GetType() == typeof(ProcessorAOptions))
{
    return new ProcessorA((ProcessorAOptions)opt);
}
else if(opt.GetType() == typeof(ProcessorBOptions))
{
    return new ProcessorB((ProcessorBOptions)opt);
}
etc.. etc..
```

This works, but seems a little inefficient, especially if I have a lot of Processor types.

Another option would be to use conventions and reflection. For example find a class which implements `IProcessor`, and has a constructor which takes the specific `IOptions` type as a parameter. Or find a class with a name that equals the name of the options class with the "Options" suffix removed (ProcessorBOptions -> ProcessorB).

Is there a better option the using reflection? Overall is there a better way to split the code that references the 3rd party API and the code that doesn't into classes in separate assemblies that are some how mapped to one another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your last method is similar to how `WebRequest` works in the CLR. You pass a Uri to `Create`, and it returns the correct subclass to work with.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest(v=vs.110).aspx

If you look at the reference source for `WebRequest.Create`, you can run through some of the patterns Microsoft uses:

http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/WebRequest.cs,117

http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/Internal.cs,1608

Generally, it boils down to picking the name of the type from an internal lookup and using `Activator.CreateInstance` to return the correct derived type.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance(v=vs.110).aspx